# Separate function with same class name by querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript

I got some functions where the div width will be changed if someone clicks the corresponding button.

I got multiple divs to need the same function, so I use `querySelectorAll` to get all the elements with class. However, the problem is that all the div widths will be changed at the same time when the button is clicked.

How do I separate them like if I click the button of the first part, only the div from the first part will be affected; If I click the button of the second part, only the div from the second part will be affected.

Even I can duplicate the Javascript then rename the function for the different parts to achieve this result, but it's not making sense. As if I got 100 divs, then I'll have to duplicate 100 times. Please run the below code for a clearer illustration.

```js
const settings = {
  Desktop: {
    width: "100%",
    gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(2,minmax(200px,1fr))"
  },
  Tablet: {
    width: "60%",
    gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(1,minmax(200px,1fr))"
  },
  Phone: {
    width: "30%",
    gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(1,minmax(200px,1fr))"
  }
}

function resize(which) {
  let x = document.querySelectorAll(".Container");
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.width = settings[which].width;
  }
  x = document.querySelectorAll(".Setting");
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.gridTemplateColumns = settings[which].gridTemplateColumns;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: grey;
}

.hr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.Medium {
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.Container {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.9s;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.Setting {
  align-items: stretch;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 30px;
  grid-row-gap: 30px;
  display: grid;
  text-align: left;
}

.Content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="hr">
  <button class="Desktop" onclick="resize('Desktop')">Desktop</button>
  <button class="Medium" onclick="resize('Tablet')">Tablet</button>
  <button class="Full" onclick="resize('Phone')">Phone</button>
</div>
<div class="Container">
  <p>First Part</p>
  <div class="Setting">
    <div class="Content"></div>
    <div class="Content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="hr">
  <button class="Desktop" onclick="resize('Desktop')">Desktop</button>
  <button class="Medium" onclick="resize('Tablet')">Tablet</button>
  <button class="Full" onclick="resize('Phone')">Phone</button>
</div>
<div class="Container">
  <p>Second Part</p>
  <div class="Setting">
    <div class="Content"></div>
    <div class="Content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance Sorry, it's my mistake and I already edited it. I mean if you click the first row of any button, only the div from the first part will be affected; If you click the second row of any button, only the div from the second part will be affected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step would be to remove the inline handlers, since they're universally considered to be horrible practice and have no reason being in modern code.

You can iterate over each `.Container` and attach an event listener to the previous sibling - the button `.hr` section. On a button click, get the text content of the clicked button to figure out which `settings` property needs to be accessed, and assign it to the style of the container being iterated over.

```js
const settings = {
  Desktop: {
    width: "100%",
    gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(2,minmax(200px,1fr))"
  },
  Tablet: {
    width: "60%",
    gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(1,minmax(200px,1fr))"
  },
  Phone: {
    width: "30%",
    gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(1,minmax(200px,1fr))"
  }
};

for (const container of document.querySelectorAll('.Container')) {
  container.previousElementSibling.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (!e.target.matches('button')) return;
    const resizeToObj = settings[e.target.textContent];
    container.style.width = resizeToObj.width;
    container.querySelector('.Setting').style.gridTemplateColumns = resizeToObj.gridTemplateColumns;
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: grey;
}

.hr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.Medium {
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.Container {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.9s;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.Setting {
  align-items: stretch;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 30px;
  grid-row-gap: 30px;
  display: grid;
  text-align: left;
}

.Content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="hr">
  <button class="Desktop">Desktop</button>
  <button class="Medium">Tablet</button>
  <button class="Full">Phone</button>
</div>
<div class="Container">
  <p>First Part</p>
  <div class="Setting">
    <div class="Content"></div>
    <div class="Content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="hr">
  <button class="Desktop">Desktop</button>
  <button class="Medium">Tablet</button>
  <button class="Full">Phone</button>
</div>
<div class="Container">
  <p>Second Part</p>
  <div class="Setting">
    <div class="Content"></div>
    <div class="Content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But `gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(1,minmax(200px,1fr))"` isn't working? And what if I wanna add more styling on it?

Comment: Oh, I missed that you needed to apply the style to separate elements. Just select the `.Setting` to assign the columns. If you want to add more styling, add more stuff to the `settings` object and assign to properties of descendants as needed.